# Format Painter is triggering my function

Tags: format

My spreadsheet is designed such that whenever I update a field with a new value, a sub within my macro is called.

However, I discovered that whenever I apply the Format Painter to the field (strictly the Format Painter; not a value update), the sub is being called.  I do not want the sub to be called in this scenario.

How can I code it so that the sub is only called on a value update, and not a formatting update?

The sub that is automatically being called is pasted below:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

```
    CellChange Target   ' Do validations etc.
```

End Sub

Comment: You should post the code you have so far. It's far easier to make a small change to your code than write something from scratch.

Comment: The code has been added to my original entry.  Thanks.